# How to use ARRAYFORMULA and SUM together to get a column with the sum of the preceeding columns?

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have the following data:

```
    |   A |  B  |  C  |  ...  | N  | TOTALS       |
  1 |  123|  425|  324|  ...  | 234| =SUM(A1:N1)  |
  2 |  123|  425|  324|  ...  | 234| =SUM(A2:N2)  |
  3 |  123|  425|  324|  ...  | 234| =SUM(A3:N3)  |
```

How can I create the `TOTALS` column using ARRAYFORMULA?

<sub>`ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(A1:C99))` will give a single number, the sum of all the cells — that’s not what I want.</sub>

Comment: There's a great answer on StackOverflow using the new LAMBDA function. ```=BYROW(A:N; LAMBDA(x; SUM(x)))```. I'm not submitting it as an answer as it's not my work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797621/arrayformula-sum-in-google-spreadsheet

Answer (score 14):

Use the following formula to do that.

### Formula

```
=MMULT(B2:E4,TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(B2:E4)^0)))
```

### Explained

The `ARRAYFORMULA` is meant to return the complete range, as set by the `COLUMN` formula. The `^0 (power of zero)` will always return 1. Therefore each result is multiplied by 1 (yielding the same value) and summed.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[SUM OVER ROWS](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdEVPWGpHNXB4RkwxYkg3QVlXRXNmNFE&usp=sharing)**

Comment: @YisraelDov, remember to mark the answer as accepted if it was what you were looking for.

Comment: This is a remarkable answer.

Comment: Any idea on how to make it work with blank cells? (to be treated as 0)

Comment: @MichaelLitvin: try this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(B1:E1),ROW(B2:E4)),ROW(B2:E4),B2:E4))`. ht to @AdamL.

Comment: To handle empty, one option is to use `indirect` instead of range. In my case I used this `indirect("e3:y"&max(arrayformula((index(E3:Y,0,0)<>"")*row(E3:Y))))`

Answer (score 3):

How about manually summing the columns:

```
=arrayformula(A:A + B:B + C:C)
```

Comment: Can’t be sure the poster meant `N` as a placeholder for a unknown number of columns or if the poster really meant column N. If the number of columns cannot be determined ahead of time, then explicitly naming each and every column in the formulae is not an option.

Comment: This can be cumbersome if you have lots of columns

Answer (score 0):

Use a modified version of the answer by Jacob to include blank cells.

```
=MMULT(arrayformula(B2:E4 * 1),TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(COLUMN(B2:E4)^0)))
```

Alternatively, you can use the following simpler form as well (excludes column function, please note the difference in the second cell reference B2:E2 instead of B2:E4):

```
=MMULT(arrayformula(B2:E4 * 1),TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(B2:E2^0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking collection of data to be summed as `B2:E4`;

Simplified version of SUM OVER ROWS, coercing blanks to zeroes:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(B2:E4*1,TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:E4))^0))
```

Corollary: SUM OVER COLUMNS, coercing blanks to zeroes:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:E4))^0,B2:E4*1))
```