# How can I sum a row in Google Spreadsheet so that the formula isn't overwritten when Google Forms adds a new row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'm using Google Forms to collect some data from students. Each time a new student submits a form, the data (4 columns worth) is added to a new row in a Google Spreadsheets, bumping anything previously in that row. It will also replace any formulas I have written in columns outside of the data range (they'll be left blank).

Note: because I am using certain features (trigger script upon submission) of the AutoCrat script I have to do all this in the **old versions** of Google Forms & Spreadsheets...

I have been able to "score" each results by adding an answer key as the first form submission in row 2 and then comparing incoming answers to it with an ArrayFormula in columns G to J (e.g., `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C3:C=C$2,1,0))` and so one for each column to be scored).

However, I've run into a problem, since I can't seem to write an ARRAYFORMULA to place in column K that simply sums the row from columns G-J. I've tried lots of ways, but I'm sure the syntax is just off. Does anyone know a way?

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432204/how-can-i-apply-a-formula-to-new-form-inserted-rows-of-data-in-google-spreadshe), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315047/how-to-add-a-row-and-have-the-last-column-be-a-copied-formula-in-google-docs), and [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53418/how-can-i-use-arrayformula-and-sum-together-to-get-a-column-with-the-sum-of-the/53419#53419),  but they haven't helped.

Here is an MWE of the [Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1NNCcljLY5mvlwP1pZfVHRjqjMqJluQLB7NBf5wgHqhA/viewform?usp=send_form) and [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1irCaXM4Hq55dZ2KartJ37hU8yq9ERHrqHEOXy-dbpt8/edit?usp=sharing)

Data goes into columns A-F, the data in C-F is scored with ArrayFormulas in G-J and a flubbed attempt at summing the scores is in column K.
Feel feel to edit the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=ArrayFormula(G2:G+H2:H+I2:I+J2:J)
```