# I have a Google Form that feeds into a Google Sheet. I need to pipe that information into another tab/cell in a dynamic way based on a data validation

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Lets see if I can explain this well enough...

I have a spreadsheet "Main_page" that is dynamically pulling information from a secondary sheet, "All_shots". I also have 2 google forms that are activated via buttons on "Main_page".

The google forms ask questions which pipe into two response pages.

What I'm trying to figure out is a way to do a vlookup that can interpret the data in a dynamic way.

The "Main Page" has dynamic information tied to cell C2. C2 is a data validation drop down that has a list of shot names. These shots names are pulled from column A2-A76 in "All_Shots"

So what I need to happen, and I cannot seem to wrap my head around how to do this....

I need a series of checks to happen and then a result to occur based on those checks.

On "Main_page" I need a script or a formula to look at "Main_page!C2" if that result is (for example) "FO_VFX_010" then I need it to look at my two form response pages to pull data

Form response page one: "Shot_version". "Shot_version" needs to pull information from all of its cells in each row.

For instance. "Shot_version!B2" should be the thing to match to in "Main_page!C2" that's the first part. once the script/formula has matched those two entries it needs to look at the next cell to the right which is "version_number"  this will be a list of numbers in the format of v001, v002.v003 etc.

Somehow, and here's where I'm stuck, I need to have either a "countif" or a "vlookup" to make the determination where that info is piped.

I want user input via a google form, to answer the following questions and then pipe the answers into "Main_page" but those answers will change to match whatever is in "Main_page!C2"

So the Google Form asks:

Shot Number (dropdown with list)
Version number (dropdown with list)
Artist's notes (paragraph)
Date submitted (calendar)
Shot Status (drop down list)

On the "Main_page!H11" I want to dynamically take the contents of "Shot_version!B2 & "_" & C2"
So in this example "Main_page!H11" would read as "FO_VFX_010_v001"

Then M11 would have the date pulled from "Shot_version!E2"

The major hurdle I'm having is if all of that is piped in, and I change the dropdown in "Main_page!C2" going from "FO_VFX_010" to "FO_VFX_020" I need the contents of "Main_page!H11" to update to match the google form entry for that shot. so "Main_page!H11" would then read "FO_VFX_020_v001"

I have records under "Main_page!H11" that need to do the same thing. So "Main_page!H11" is v001
"Main_page!H13" is v002 (some merged cells in there) "Main_page!H15" is v003 etc.

To add insult to injury I have the same issue with my second Google Form.

"Main_page!O11" needs to reference "Client_notes!D2" but only if it first matches "Client_notes!B2" I need some way for the version number to be the thing that drives which cell gets which information.. and it has to dynamically switch whenever I change "Main_page!C2"

Everything is tied to "Main_page!C2". It's driving a bunch of other stuff using vlookup and a few other kitchen sink things. But I can't seem to make that work for these cells. not sure what I'm doing wrong.

For instance I currently have:

```
=vlookup(C2,Shot_version!$B$2:$C$79,1,0) & "_" & vlookup(C2,Shot_version!$B$2:$C$79,2,0)
```

This does return the correct information as long as I'm on "Main_page!C2" with the dropdown set to "FO_VFX_010"

If I change it to "FO_VFX_020", ALL of my "Main_page!H" cells change to the same answer of "FO_VFX_020_v001" I can't figure out what I'm missing!

Oh and bonus points, I'd like the status in "Main_page!G5" to match whatever the most recent entry is on the "Shot_version!G2:G" column is. So if it's ready for review on v001, but it's rendering on v002, status would update to "rendering"

[Here's what Main_page looks like with the name set to "FO_VFX_010"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC1ul.png)

[Here's what Main_page looks like with the name set to "FO_VFX_020"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMAKN.png)

[This is what the google form results look like for "Client_notes"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O4wa.png)

[This is what the google form results look like for "Shot_version"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuERx.png)

Comment: To do "a vlookup that can interpret the data in a dynamic way" use an ARRAYFORMULA and open ended references.

Comment: Related [How can I sum a row in Google Spreadsheet so that the formula isn't overwritten when Google Forms adds a new row?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/66344/88163) (this has a very short answer),  [Arrayformula+VLOOKUP find value of non-empty reference (callback/recursion problem)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/105689/88163) (this has a long answer b/c uses a complex formula). Many more --> https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-forms%5D+arrayformula+vlookup

Comment: I've never done an array formula. I'm not yet very good at scripting, mostly cobbling things together, so I don't quite understand the mechanics or the "why" things work yet. 

I'm actually struggling mostly with how to parse the information, along with how to get the formula to work.

Comment: Read [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) and [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

Comment: I need some help on parsing.

Trying to do a vlookup then an array formula to check the column, (open ended) on my "Shot_version!" form response

=vlookup(C2, ARRAYFORMULA({Shot_version!$B$2: $B$})

That does not return anything. As far as I understand it, that should give me an open ended value for column B2 on down. So that as new entries are made, the Vlookup will acknowledge them.

Once that comparison is made matching "Main _page!C2" to the Array formula of "Shot_version"  I don't know how to then get the rest of the info into the appropriate cells on "Main_page!" Specifically H12

Comment: Can the vlookup/ array take into account two columns on the form response? 

Mainly.. if I'm using a "match exactly" comparison with the vlookup to match C2 on Main page to the B column on the form response but I also want to make sure it's checking the version number in collumn C of the form response.

If it meets both criteria then it should be piped into the H column on "Main_page!"

The Example being.. "Main_page!C2" matches "Shot_version!B2:B" then look to column C on "Shot_version!" to get the version number

The end result being "Main_page!H12" reads "FO_VFX_010_v001"